# Roadblock using generics in jax-rs rest services using jpa

Tags: java, jpa, jax-rs

I am writing a rest service that exposes a relational database.  I have three layers in the application:

1. Persistence layer (the JPA entities)
2. EJB layer
3. Rest layer

For each entity, the methods that I am implementing are: `add`, `update`, `findAll`, `findById`.  I am using Java generics in both the **Rest layer** and the **EJB layer** in order to write as little code as possible.

But I have hit a road block in the **EJB layer** implementing the method `findById`, because some entities of the database have an `Integer` type primary key, and others have a `String` type primary key.  The generic EJB implementation is as follows:

```
public abstract class SimpleEJB <T extends Object> {

    //This entity is injected by the container.
    @PersistenceContext(name="PersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager em;

    private Class<?> TClass;

    public SimpleEJB(Class<?> entityClass){
        this.TClass = entityClass;
    }

    public T findById(String id){
        T t = this.em.find(this.TClass, id);
        return t;
    }
}
```

I don't want to write abstract classes (on rest layer and ejb layer) for each different primary key type that I may find (Integer, String, Date, etc). Since the rest layer receives a primary key as a `String` in the url, can I just pass that `String` to the EJB layer, and will the `find` method `EntityManager` automatically convert that `String` into the type of T, or am I forced to write different abstract classes for each different primary key type?

Side note: I cannot change the database.

Comment: This might not answer your question directly. I have a couple of alternatives - see if they help (1) Try the netbeans IDE tooling which can automatically generate REST services from database tables - https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html#create-services-from-db (2) heard of jpa-rs ? Its a functionality in eclipselink 2.4 onwards. All you need is your jpa persistence.xml and include eclipselink specific WAR with your app and see the magic. More here - http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLADG/restful_jpa.htm#TLADG809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you can just do some reflection on the `TClass` to get the type of the `id` field (assuming that's the common name of the "id" field) and just conditionally set the PK to check . Something like

```
public T findById(String id) throws Exception {
    Field idField = TClass.getDeclaredField("id");
    Class<?> type = idField.getType();
    Object pk = id;
    if (type == Integer.class) {
        pk = Integer.parseInt(id);
    }
    return manager.find(TClass, pk);
}
```

For a more generic approach (where you don't need to know the name of the field), you could alternatively check for the `@Id` annotation on all the fields. Whichever one has the annotation, will be the type you want to parse. For example

```
public T findById(String id) throws Exception {
    Field[] declaredFields = TClass.getDeclaredFields();
    Field idField = null;
    for (Field field: declaredFields) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Id.class)) {
            idField = field;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (idField == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No field annotated with @Id");
    }
    Class<?> type = idField.getType();
    Object pk = id;
    if (type == Integer.class) {
        pk = Integer.parseInt(id);
    }
    return manager.find(TClass, pk);
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot. I will be using the one checking for the @Id annotation on all the fields.